# Is there a word for human litter-mates?

Tags: meaning, single-word-requests, synonyms

If my brother and I shared a womb during gestation (as humans) we're twins. If there was another sibling in there we're triplets.. and so on, but is there a general term to describe us irrespective of how many of us there were?

I know we're siblings, but I'm curious if there's a word analogous to siblings that refers specifically to members of a single human litter.

For that matter is there an alternate word for a human litter? Or is it correct to refer to triplets as a litter?

Comment: So you want a word for a "member of a multiple birth" rather than *sibling,* "member of multiple children"? [This comment might answer your supplementary question, I suppose]

Comment: @AndrewLeach, yes, I'm hoping there's such a word. I'm actually looking to use it in a technical biological context; describing research to be done on [siblings gestated simultaneously in the womb].  Was wondering if there's a more elegant way to describe them. [edit] Ah! so "multiple birth" refers to a human litter. Excellent... 1/2 the problem is solved :)

Comment: May I coin the word wombmate?

Comment: wombfellow sounds more distingished.

Comment: I think describing a multiple human birth as a litter is likely to get you a smack in the mouth by the mom.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Siblings from a *multiple birth* are called **[multiples](http://kidshealth.org/parent/positive/family/parenting_multiples.html)**. Three or more offspring from the same birth are called *higher-order multiples*. For describing specific numbers of offspring, the terms are *[singlets](http://pregnancy.about.com/od/multiplepregnancy/f/howmanybabies.htm)* (1), *twins* (2), *triplets* (3), *quadruplets* (4), *quintuplets* (5), *sextuplets* (6), *septuplets* (7), and *octuplets* (8). (Multiples higher than this are almost impossible for humans.)

Comment: @Dr.Dredel My pleasure. I was hoping that the term would utilize the suffix _-tuplets_, but alas, it does not.

Comment: _Multuplets_ really should be a word. Or _multipluplets_.

Comment: Yes, but _He's my multiple_ would not be understood without context, whereas _He's my twin_ would. (I'm not sure about _He's my triplet_ - I would expect _He's one of my triplets_, but even that does not seem quite natural).

Comment: @ColinFine You are right; because of the many denotations of _multiple_, if someone said _He's my multiple_, he would probably be met with perplexed looks. (In fact, because a _multiple_ usually means "something in units of more than one or two", he and his sibling may be mistaken as clones!)

Comment: I should have said "_multiple_ denotations of _multiple_"!

Comment: Better than *multuplets* would be just *tuplets*.  He and she are my tuplets... and there are even more of us!

Comment: @Drew The term _tuplet_ is precise and concise; however, tuplet is used in music and mathematics, so it may cause some puzzlement as well.

Comment: @Theodore: Actually, that was one reason I suggested coining it. (But in Math, at least, it is **tuple**, not **tuplet**.)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you'll find a more well defined term than *litter*, which is surprising as human tend to like to distance themselves from the rest of the mammals.

*Littermate* **is** the word for an individual offspring born in one litter, regardless of which species of mammal.

Comment: Yes, but it would be exceedingly odd (to the degree that I would expect it not to be understood) if used of humans.

Answer (score -1):

A pluriparity

**[Pluriparous](http://useful_english.enacademic.com/736769/pluriparous)**: Being the mother of two or more children

Comment: That doesn’t apply if the litter is only one child, so it’s not quite irrespective of how many there are. Also, _pluriparity_ [describes the mother](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/pluriparity), not the litter/children.

Comment: @Third News, is there an adjective for being the kind of person who offers useful looking answers on Stack that upon closer examination bear no actual relevance to the original question? ;-)

Comment: @Dr.Dredel yes, there is ;-)

Comment: @ Janus Bahs Jacquet does a litter apply to one offspring? Hmm....